# FBDriver reporting warnings I can't figure out how to fix

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I'm developing a RESTful application and whenever I make a request, it works fine, but also outputs these warnings:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: null
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection.isValid does not support non-zero timeouts, timeout value 5 has been ignored
```

Using Spring Boot framework with Hibernate, HikariCP, QueryDSL and a Firebird database using the Jaybird 4.0.5.java11 version.

Here is my `application.yml` file where I setup the connection with my database:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
    url: jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\\path\\to\\my\\database.fdb?encoding=win1252
    username: myuser
    password: mypassword
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 1000
      login-timeout: 1000
      minimum-idle: 10

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

I've tried all options I could to setup a timeout but none of them made the timeout warning go away.

Also, I can't figure out that SQL Warning Code: 0, from what I've gathered so far, it means it worked, but why is it outputting a warning?

I should mention that I've altered some sensitive information and they were replaced with `path\\to\\my\\database.fdb`, `myuser` and `mypassword`, but these settings work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that Jaybird currently doesn't support a timeout for [`Connection.isValid(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) and ignores it, and thus - if the specified timeout is non-zero - it [registers a `SQLWarning`](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/blob/v4.0.5/src/main/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/FBConnection.java#L488) on the connection (instead of throwing an exception). Although registering a warning here isn't specified in the JDBC specification, this is similar to what JDBC requires a driver to do when it replaces/ignores user-specified values when configuring the result set type, concurrency and holdability.

When Hibernate notices there is a warning registered on the connection, it will log that warning in `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper`. This logging of warnings can be disabled by setting the property `hibernate.jdbc.log.warnings=false` (see [Query Settings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-query) in the Hibernate documentation). In case of Spring Boot, I guess you can set this as property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.log.warnings` (but I haven't verified this).

The timeout is configurable through the HikariCP property `validationTimeout`, but - by default - this doesn't accept a value lower than 250 milliseconds (you can change that with system property [`com.zaxxer.hikari.timeoutMs.floor`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1735)). Alternatively, you can configure HikariCP property `connectionTestQuery` with - for example - `select 1 from rdb$database`, so HikariCP uses the test query instead of `Connection.isValid(int)`. Be aware that a test query has more overhead.

The warning code printed is the `SQLWarning.getErrorCode()` (technically, [`SQLException.getErrorCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode()), a.k.a the vendor code). And given this warning doesn't have an error/warning code, its value is 0, which simply means *"there is no specific vendor code associated with this warning"*.

I have created [this issue](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/issues/685) to see if actual timeout support can be added in Jaybird 4.0.6 or Jaybird 5.

Disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of Jaybird.

Comment: I'll follow the github issue you created to check for a "fix" for this "issue". Thanks a lot for the taking some time to answer my concerns!